# Bad response on API request pagination

Tags: linkedin-api

There's appear to be a bug in the Linkedin API
I'm using the get organization activity API, with pagination, and when calling the next page (through the href attribute in the nextLink field), I get a response with 0 elements (empty array), and a nextLink link with the same href I just used. example:

Request Url:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?count=1&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A9180416&q=owners&start=5

Response payload:

```
{
  "elements": [],
  "paging": {
   "total": 216,
   "count": 1,
   "start": 5,
   "links": [
     {
       "rel": "prev",
       "href": "/v2/shares? 
   count=1&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A9180416&q=owners&start=4",
       "type": "application/json"
     },
     {
       "rel": "next",
       "href": "/v2/shares? 
   count=1&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A9180416&q=owners&start=5",
       "type": "application/json"
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

Do I send the request in a bad way?